# A prime dividing a number in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $p\equiv 1\text{ mod }{4}$. Then there exists an integer $n$ such that $p|n^2+1=(n+i)(n-i)$. Suppose $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Then $p$ is also prime, and so we must have $p|n+i$ or $p|n-i$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. I am trying to understand a line in the proof which says "it is easy to see" that if  $p|n+i$ then we also have $p|n-i$.

I'm not sure if the congruence condition on $p$ plays any role here, but anyway I am having trouble seeing why it's true. What am I missing?

Comment: I think there is some error, if $p$ divides **both** $n-i$ and $n+i$, then $p=2$ (OR are you trying to get a contradiction.)

Comment: Why? If $p$ divides them both then $p|2n$.

Comment: $p$ also divides the difference which is $2i$.

Comment: I am looking at page 5 of these notes: https://people.math.gatech.edu/~mbaker/pdf/ANTBook.pdf

Comment: Your quotes are from the $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ paragraph, but your question starts with $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. I've made the edit.

Comment: Ok. If $n+i=p\alpha$, then take conjugate ($n-i=p\bar{\alpha}$) to claim that $p$ divides $n-i$.

Comment: Of course. Thanks.